# How to run the RegexMatchingEventHandler of Watchdog correctly?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, watchdog, python-watchdog

I'm working on a small tool for a GameApi. This Api works with .log-files. They are provided in a specific location. I want to observe this location with with watchdog and it is working fine, if I use the PatternMatchingEventHandler. But if I use the RegexMatchingEventHandler it fails. I want to use Regex because there a many .log-files and I only want to check the files from today.

Extension: I use Watchdog with the functions:

```py
on_created
on_deleted
on_moved
on_modified
```

This Website shows the code I am using:
https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2019/01/how-to-create-a-watchdog-in-python-to-look-for-filesystem-changes/

I tested my Regex function normaly with re. This is doing absolutly fine. But even if I try the Regex Entry: ['\w+.log'] it did not work.

I provide you my Regex to understand what I want to do:

```py
regexes = ["^Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$"]
```

I expected a message everytime I change one of my .log-files but this is only happend i f i use the PatternMatchingEventHAndle

EDIT:
Now I present you you my minimal Example:

```py
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import RegexMatchingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    regexes = ["^Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$"]
    ignore_regexes= []
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True
    my_event_handler = RegexMatchingEventHandler(regexes,ignore_regexes,ignore_directories,case_sensitive)

    def on_modified(event):
        print(f"hey buddy, {event.src_path} has been modified")

    my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified

# Observer
    path = "."
    go_recursively = True
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)

    my_observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
        my_observer.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just about the pattern of the path returned by the event handler, it begins by the path to the root of the folder specified in `path` (`path = "."` in your example) .

- It can help to inspect any patterns of the paths returned, and check what you need exactly:

  ```
  regexes = ['.+']  # will match everything
  ```
- To track files in the current directory with `path = "."`:

  ```
  # linux (example path : ./Journal[...].log)
  regexes = ['^\./Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$']

  # windows (example path : .\Journal[...].log)
  regexes = ["^\.\\\\Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$"]

  # both
  regexes = ["^\.(/|\\\\)Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$"]
  ```
- if you define a subfolder named `logs` and you specify the root like `path = "logs"`

  ```
  # (example path : logs/Journal[...].log or logs\Journal[...].log
  regexes = ['^logs(/|\\\\)logs/Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$']
  ```

Comment: Ok I understand the thing with the path. This code is running on a windows system, do I have to do something special? To get my correct path I use: ```from pathlib import Path```

Comment: hmm i was thinking about this, i tried it on linux, what is the path returned if you use `['.+']` ? i'm not sure how it handles the backslash on windows paths.

Comment: that was my thinking too. How can I read the output of ['.+']. should I do it with import re?

Comment: i was suggesting that to replace your current `regexes = ["^Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$"]` to check what is the pattern returned on windows

Comment: Ah Ok yeah that works. With .log and .txt as expected. And just to mention I tested my regex with  regex tester before.

Comment: but I dont understand why my complete regex is not working.

Comment: Can you try `regexes = ["\.\\\\Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$"]` ? Otherwise  `regexes = [".+Journal\.190901\d{6}\.\d{2}\.log$"]` could work too

Comment: I am currently at work and check this if I am at home. I want to check different Files with same pattern: They all start with "Journal." followed by the date the file was writen like "190901" with actual timestamp that doesn't matter with the pattern "010101.01" and the files endings are ".log". Alltogether: "Journal.190901010101.01.log"

Comment: That worked both. I dont get why you have to use 4 backslashes in the first regex, but thank you very much. Still Windows is weird :) I will edit your awnser to mark it as solution. I see you did already.

Comment: glad it works ;) Regex can be as weird as Windows too, to write a litteral backslash, you have to use 4 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)