# Python watchdog Watch For the Creation of New File By Pattern Match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-watchdog

I'm still learning Python so I apologize up front. I am trying to write a watcher that watches for the creation of a file that matches a specific pattern. I am using watchdog with some code that is out there to get it watch a directory.

I don't quite understand how to have the watcher watch for a filename that matches a pattern. I've edited the `regexes=[]` field with what I think might work but I have not had luck.

Here is an example of a file that might come in: `Hires For Monthly TM_06Jan_0946.CSV`

I can get the watcher to tell me when a .CSV is created in the directory, I just can't get it to only tell me when essentially `Hires.*\.zip` is created.

I've checked the this link but have not had luck
[How to run the RegexMatchingEventHandler of Watchdog correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746487/how-to-run-the-regexmatchingeventhandler-of-watchdog-correctly)

Here is my code:

````
import time
import watchdog.events 
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import RegexMatchingEventHandler
import re
import watchdog.observers 
import time
import fnmatch
import os

class Handler(watchdog.events.RegexMatchingEventHandler): 
    def __init__(self): 
        watchdog.events.RegexMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, regexes=['.*'], ignore_regexes=[], ignore_directories=False, case_sensitive=False) 

    def on_created(self, event): 
        print("Watchdog received created event - % s." % event.src_path) 


    def on_modified(self, event): 
        print("Watchdog received modified event - % s." % event.src_path) 



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    src_path = r"C:\Users\Downloads"
    event_handler = Handler() 
    observer = watchdog.observers.Observer() 
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=src_path, recursive=True) 
    observer.start() 
    try: 
        while True: 
            time.sleep(1) 
    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        observer.stop() 
    observer.join() ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `'.*'` regex works and while the `Hires.*\.zip` regex doesn't is watchdog tries to match the full path with the regex. In terms of regex: `r'Hires.*\.zip'` will not give you a full match with "C:\Users\Downloads\Hires blah.zip"

Instead, try:

```
def __init__(self): 
    watchdog.events.RegexMatchingEventHandler.__init__(
            self, regexes=[r'^.*?\.cvs$', r'.*?Hires.*?\.zip'],
            ignore_regexes=[], ignore_directories=False, case_sensitive=False)
```

This will match with all the cvs files and the zip files starts with "Hires". The `'.*?'` matches with "C:\Users\Downloads" and the rest ensures file types, file names etc.

Comment: Thanks! Here is what worked:
`class ExampleHandler(RegexMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(event.src_path)
        downloads = event.src_path
        if len(downloads) >= 1:
            observer.stop()
                        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pattern = '.*Hires.*\.zip'
    event_handler = ExampleHandler(regexes=[pattern], ignore_directories=True) 
    observer = Observer()
    path = r"C:\Users\wdenham\Downloads"
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    import time
    observer.join()`