# Watchdog not triggering event for pattern

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm using watchdog to monitor a directory for a specific file pattern.

My file name looks like this: myfile-yyyymmdd.csv. The pattern I'm trying to use is: myfile-*.csv

The directory where I'm placing the file is: .../imp/myDir/

The watch_directory being passed to FileWatch is: .../imp

I am initializing the observer with recursive=True.

My code does not work when I use the pattern myfile-*.csv. It does work if I use the pattern *.csv.

I'm not sure if there is a problem in my code or if this is a limitation.

Here's a code snippet.

```
class FileWatch(): 
    def __init__(self, watch_directory, patterns, commands, log): 
        self.script_name     = "FileWatch()"
        self.observer        = PollingObserver() 
        self.watch_directory = watch_directory
        self.patterns        = patterns
        self.commands        = commands
        self.log             = log

    def run(self): 
        self.event_handler = Handler(self.log, self.commands, patterns=self.patterns) 
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.watch_directory, recursive=True) 
        self.observer.start() 

        try: 
            while True: 
                time.sleep(5) 

        except: 
            self.observer.stop() 
            log.error(logMessage(self.script_name, "Observer Stopped.") )

        self.observer.join() 


class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler): 
    def __init__(self, log, commands, patterns=None):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(patterns=patterns)

        self.log = log
        self.commands = commands

    def on_created(self, event): 
        script_name = "Handler - on_created()"

        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        on_event_action("created", event.src_path, self.commands, self.log)

    def on_modified(self, event): 
        script_name = "Handler - on_modified()"

        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        on_event_action("modified", event.src_path, self.commands, self.log)
```

The on_event_action() is a function that checks to make sure the file size is stable then moves the file.

I am calling FileWatch like this:

```
   watch = FileWatch(watch_directory, patterns, commands, log)
   watch.run()
```

Has anyone run into this problem before? And if so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by switching to RegexMatchingExentHandler as illustrated [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764150/python-watchdog-watch-for-the-creation-of-new-file-by-pattern-match)

Now I need to refine the regex pattern. When my process finds the file it moves it to a sub-directory and creates a .trg file in the same location. The .trg creation is triggering another created event.

My regex pattern is `'.*myfile.*\.csv'`. I'm new to regex so I'm not sure what about my pattern is allowing it to find myfile_20200413.csv.trg.

Aside from the regex pattern I would say my initial problem is solved as my code now triggers an event based on a pattern and also works for sub-directories.